# Outlook 2016 muestra deshabilitado el get Add-ins

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft

Estoy intentando instalar un add in en outlook 2016, y cuando añado la opción Get Add ins a la tab addins, me muestra la opción desabilitada. También he intentado instalar mi adding cargando el manifest.xml desde el proyecto, no me admite ese tipo de fichero. y el sideloading debería segun la documentación instalarlo automaticamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De repente alguna sugerencia ?

Nota: estoy usuando un office patcheado.

Comment: Etiqueta Nodejs? Y pues, creo que esa opción requiere asociar una cuenta microsoft. Si tienes un com complement, ese lo puedes instalar en File > Options > Addins.

Comment: Estoy, conectado con una cuenta personal de outlook. No sabia que esto podía influir en la posibilidad de habilitar la opcion Get Add in

Comment: Yo tampoco pero pues [ahí tienes](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/get-add-ins-for-outlook-2019-is-disabled/5d319896-700b-4b1c-9afc-a75ad3c79090). Cosas de Microsoft